# Replace value in json during run time

Tags: bash

I am trying to replace value on run time in json i.e.

Old

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "name": "containername",
    "image": "myimage",
    "memory": 512,
    "cpu": 1,
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [{
      "hostPort": 80,
      "containerPort": 80,
      "protocol": "tcp"
    }]
  }],
  "volumes": [],
  "family": "containername"
}
```

New should be

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "name": "containername",
    "image": "new image",
    "memory": 512,
    "cpu": 1,
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [{
      "hostPort": 80,
      "containerPort": 80,
      "protocol": "tcp"
    }]
  }],
  "volumes": [],
  "family": "containername"
}
```

- Old value: - "image": "myimage"
- New Value: - "image": "new image"

I want to do in bash. Is there any best way to do? Can we do through jq?

Comment: Is it something special or just normal word replacing?

Comment: value can be anything.

so it should check the keyword "image" and replace the value

Answer (score 14):

You can use jq for this:

```
jq '.containerDefinitions[].image="new image"' old.son
```

Answer (score 4):

You should really use a tool or library that understands JSON. But if your input looks as above, you can use [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
$ sed -i '/"image": "myimage"/s/"myimage"/"new image"/' input.json
```

Comment: This will not work for anything but simple things.  Any solution provided should ensure proper json encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Given that `linux` does not by itself allow redirection to the same file, you can use the `sponge` utility from `moreutils` package

```
- apt update && apt install -y moreutils
- jq '.json_label="json_value"' file.json | sponge file.json
```

This will truly allow in line replacement;

Answer (score 1):

This is basically what user suggested, inside a minimalist script!
This uses no external programs but depends on bash!

Your new json will be stored in the `newStr` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

str='
{
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "name": "containername",
    "image": "myimage",
    "memory": 512,
    "cpu": 1,
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [{
      "hostPort": 80,
      "containerPort": 80,
      "protocol": "tcp"
    }]
  }],
  "volumes": [],
  "family": "containername"
}'

replaceValue='"myimage"'
replaceWith='"new image"'
newStr=${str//$replaceValue/$replaceWith}
echo $newStr
```

Output:

> { "containerDefinitions": [{ "name": "containername", "image": "new
>   image", "memory": 512, "cpu": 1, "essential": true, "portMappings": [{
>   "hostPort": 80, "containerPort": 80, "protocol": "tcp" }] }],
>   "volumes": [], "family": "containername" }

Comment: fine thanks.

Now i understood and things are working fine for me.

Comment: Works with me. Should be choosen as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should works for you:

```
oldValue='"image": "myimage"'
newValue=${oldValue//myimage/newImage}
echo newValue
```

In `oldValue` should be your json.

Comment: i want to change the json not just value

Comment: So I wrote that in `oldValue` should be your json.

Answer (score 0):

If python is reliably present, then you can use embedded python like so:

- setup multiline string
- execute and fail on error

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/evn bash
  # python as multi line string

  read -r -d '' PYSCRIPT << ENDPY
  import json
  import os
  jsonfile = 'daemon.json'
  data = {}
  if os.path.exists(jsonfile):
      data = json.load(open(jsonfile))
  data["booleanVar"] = True
  data["stringVar"] = "foo"
  with open(jsonfile, 'w') as fp:
      json.dump(data, fp)
  ENDPY

  # execute python and fail on error

  echo "$PYSCRIPT" |python - || exit 1
  ```